I can't install 24.04 LTS on the selected partition (to delete 22.04)
I am trying to delete Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my partition nvme0n1p6 (288.7 GB). I have a dual boot with Windows on nvme0n1p4 (734 GB).
But When selecting the partition in installation guide, I can't click on next. Please see the 3 screenshots below.
Step 0:

Create free space:

I can't click next:

I tried the first option with no manual partitioning, but it seems to erase my whole disk which is very much not wanted because I want to keep Windows. It says:

nvme01n1p1 created
nvme01n1p2 formatted in ext4 used for /

Is there something I should unlock to be able to reinstall Ubuntu 24.04 over 22.04?
Partition info:
| Partition       | Nom                        | Système de fichiers | Étiquette    | Taille    | Utilisé    | Inutilisé   | Drapeaux        |
|-----------------|----------------------------|----------------------|--------------|-----------|------------|-------------|-----------------|
| /dev/nvme0n1p1  | Basic data partition       | ntfs                 | Récupération | 450.00 Mio| 10.05 Mio  | 439.95 Mio  | hidden, diag    |
| /dev/nvme0n1p2  | EFI system partition       | fat32                | ---          | 100.00 Mio| ---        | ---         | boot, esp       |
| /dev/nvme0n1p3  | Microsoft reserved partition | inconnu              | ---          | 16.00 Mio | ---        | ---         | msftres         |
| /dev/nvme0n1p4  | Basic data partition       | ntfs                 | ---          | 683.59 Gio| 573.35 Gio | 110.24 Gio  | msftdata        |
| /dev/nvme0n1p6  |                            | ext4                 | ---          | 268.87 Gio| 240.89 Gio | 27.98 Gio   | ---             |
| /dev/nvme0n1p5  |                            | ntfs                 | ---          | 870.00 Mio| 592.13 Mio | 277.87 Mio  | hidden, diag    |
| non alloué      |                            | non alloué           |              | 1.34 Mio  | ---        | ---         | ---             |


Unless this is a really old legacy BIOS type install; a system requires an ESP (EFI System Partition) to be selected for modern booting, have you selected the ESP your 22.04 system used?  (ESP is mounted at /boot/efi

Thanks for the help, How can I check this information ? Here is more informations I can give you:

One way is boot your existing system & see what is mounted.. For my own system here, mount |grep sda will show sda6 is my /  (I also see another mount of it for snap packages, sda7 is another system I have added (my system is dual boot & I that is the mount I created for the other OS; its at /lts which I created) & sda1 is the /boot/efi mount which is my drive's ESP or EFI System Partition.  ... but that's only one way to see.

Here is my EFI:
dev/nvme0n1p2  EFI system partition  fat32  ---  100.00 Mio  ---  ---  boot, esp

Your third picture does NOT show you having selected that in your question... I'm suggesting you try giving the system an ESP, ie. adding /dev/nvme0n1p2 as a mount point to /boot/efi

Does this answer your question? How to uninstall Ubuntu from dual boot and change the bootloader?

How I am supposed to select /dev/nvme0n1p2 as a mount point to  /boot/efi ?
The only options are "change", "minus (-)", "reset".

@karel, By locating the Boot section and set Windows Boot Manager as the default boot option. It seems I'm now able to format the /dev/nvme0n1p6 partition with Gparted, on my flash disks ubuntu 24.04. But I'm not quite sure this is the right way to do it. Because I'm still not able to run the installation manager on the ubuntu partition. I still don't understand guiverc instructions...

Select the FAT partition and then click on the change button. There you can select the mount point /boot/efi. A bit small at 100MB, but should work.  With the minimum necessary partitions set up (ESP and root), you should be able to select location of bootloader (only one location offered in your case), and select next. I don't understand what the Windows Boot Manager has to do with anything at this point.

Problem solved. Step 1) locating the Boot section and set Windows Boot Manager as the default boot option. Step 2) Unallocate Ubuntu 22.04 with gparted. Step3) Turn off the legacy mode, but UEFI booting mode. Step 4) Install Ubuntu 24.04. It automatically proposed to install alongside windows. But I may not have a clean partition because It's full 251 Gb/283 Gb ... Is there a way to clean it ?

If I understand correctly you have 251 gb full? In that case it is better to do it in windows, go there read about how to clean up windows in websites, also you can check how much disk space you can shrink in disk manager, this might also help https://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/treesize-free-portable.
